# Will google playstore accept music player demo video which is showing song's album art?

Tags: android, google-play

I know that we cannot use album art in our music player app screenshots to be shown in google playstore. Will google playstore accept promo videos which is showing song's album art in its demo?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about programming, but about copyright annoyances in marketing.

Comment: This is off topic because it's about Google's acceptance policy, not programming

Comment: Sorry for this question in this forum. It should be closed.

Comment: StackOverflow is also not a forum. Forum is for discussions, exactly what SO is not for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Copyright infringement** is an improper or unauthorized use of a copyrighted work. If you publish an app in Google Play that uses another party's copyrighted works improperly or without permission, your apps can be suspended and your developer account terminated.

As you design your app and prepare for publishing, make sure to review Google Play policies and analyze all of your content. Make sure that app name, icon, promo screenshots and video aren't infringing on copyright.

Reference: https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/2985822